# PHP Parsing not displaying filtered CSV Data

Tags: php, csv, parsing

I'm trying to use code I found online to complete a task of displaying mobile numbers, the carrier and the validity of the mobile number on whether it is from the UK or not. The code I seen was using this PHP library (https://github.com/splitbrain/php-cli) which I have downloaded. The information must be parsed and a CSV file must display the information in the correct columns. The code I found was from this url: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/221270/php-program-to-validate-phone-numbers-from-a-file

I'm struggling to understand how the person in the above link has their code layed out. This is the error that is being displayed for me:

[image]

I have a feeling the error is to do with me laying the code out incorrectly but have no idea where this issue lies. Any help will be appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

require 'C:\UniServerZ\www\bayne_07_09_2021-3\php-cli-master\autoload.php';

use splitbrain\phpcli\CLI;
use splitbrain\phpcli\Options;
use libphonenumber\PhoneNumberUtil;
use libphonenumber\PhoneNumberToCarrierMapper;
use libphonenumber\PhoneNumberType;
use libphonenumber\NumberParseException;


class mobileValidator extends CLI
{
// override the default log level
protected $logdefault = 'info';

// register options and arguments
protected function setup(Options $options)
{
$options->setHelp('This script takes a list of phone numbers from a file (or as an option) and validates them as UK mobile numbers.');
$options->registerOption('file', 'The file containing a list of phone numbers to validate', 'f', 'filename');
$options->registerOption('numbers', 'List of numbers passed in as an option (numbers should separated by a comma).', 'n', 'numbers');
}


/**
* The main Program
* Arguments and options have been parsed when this is run
* @param Options $options
* @return void
*/

protected function main(Options $options)
{
if (!$options->getOpt('file') && !$options->getOpt('numbers')) {
    $this->error('No files or numbers have been supplied - Cannot Continue.');
    exit();
}

$this->notice('Validation Process Started');

//Get options
$opNum = $options->getOpt('numbers');
$file = $options->getOpt('file');

$numbersFromOp = array();
$numbersFromFile = array();

//Set country code uk
$countryCode = 44;

//Set regions codes to Uk, Guernsey, Jersey and Isle of Man
$regionCodes = array('GB', 'GG', 'JE', 'IM');

//get validator dependencies
$phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil::getInstance();
$carrierMapper = PhoneNumberToCarrierMapper::getInstance();
$phoneNumberType = PhoneNumberType::MOBILE;

//Get numbers from passed in option
if ($opNum) {
    $numbersFromOp = explode(',', $opNum);
}

//Check if files is set and actually exists
if ($file) {
    if(file_exists($file)) {
        $numbersFromFile = file($file);
    }
    else {
        $this->warning("File not found ".$file);
        if(!$opNum){
            $this->critical('File not found and no numbers have been supplied - Cannot Continue.');
            exit();
        }
    }
}

//marge all number arrays to be validated
$phoneNumbers = array_merge($numbersFromFile, $numbersFromOp);

//Validate the numbers
$validator = new validator($phoneNumbers, $phoneUtil, $carrierMapper, $phoneNumberType, $countryCode, $regionCodes);
$results = $validator->validateNumbers();

//write numbers to the csv file
$this->generateCSV($results);

$this->success('Validation process completed successfully');
}

/**
* generateCSV
* Simple function to write a csv file
* @param array $results
* @return void
*/

protected function generateCSV(array $results){
// Open a file to write to
$fp = fopen('output/phone_numbers_'. date('d-M-Y-H-i').'.csv' , 'wb');

$headerRow = array ('Phone Number', 'Carrier', 'Status');

$i = 0;
foreach( $results as $fields ){
    if( $i === 0 ){
        fputcsv($fp, $headerRow ); // First write the headers
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $fields); // Then write the fields
    $i++;
}
fclose($fp);
}


/**
* Override log function
* Added error_log
* @param string $level
* @param string $message
* @param array $context
*/
public function log($level, $message, array $context = array())
{
// is this log level wanted?
if (!isset($this->loglevel[$level])) return;

/** @var string $prefix */
/** @var string $color */
/** @var resource $channel */
list($prefix, $color, $channel) = $this->loglevel[$level];
if (!$this->colors->isEnabled()) $prefix = '';

$message = $this->interpolate($message, $context);
error_log($message);
$this->colors->ptln($prefix . $message, $color, $channel);
}

}
// execute it
$cli = new mobileValidator();
$cli->run();







class validator
{
private $phoneNumbers;
private $phoneUtil;
private $carrierMapper;
private $phoneNumberType;
private $countryCode;
private $regionCodes;
private const VALID = 'Valid';
private const INVALID = 'Invalid';

function __construct( array $phoneNumbers, PhoneNumberUtil $phoneUtil, 
PhoneNumberToCarrierMapper $carrierMapper, $phoneNumberType, $countryCode, $regionCodes)
{
$this->phoneNumbers = $phoneNumbers;
$this->phoneUtil = $phoneUtil;
$this->carrierMapper = $carrierMapper;
$this->phoneNumberType = $phoneNumberType;
$this->countryCode = $countryCode;
$this->regionCodes = $regionCodes;
}

/**
* Returns validated results
* Loops through the phone numbers and validates as uk mobile numbers (including the channel islands).
* Results returned as an array( number, carrier, valid)
* @return array $results
*/

public function validateNumbers(){
$results = array();
//loop through supplied phone numbers
foreach ($this->phoneNumbers as $phoneNumber) {
    $number = trim($phoneNumber);
    try {
        $phoneNumberObject = $this->phoneUtil->parse($number, 'GB');
    }
    catch (NumberParseException $e) {
        $results[] = array($number,'', self::INVALID);
        error_log($e);
        continue;
    }
    //get country code and region code
    $countryCode = $phoneNumberObject->getCountryCode();
    $regionCode = $this->phoneUtil->getRegionCodeForNumber($phoneNumberObject);
    $valid = false;

    //Number is considered valid if the country code matches supplied country code
    // and the region code matches one of the supplied region codes

    if($countryCode === $this->countryCode && in_array($regionCode, $this->regionCodes)){
        $valid = $this->phoneUtil->isValidNumber($phoneNumberObject);
    }

    $type = $this->phoneUtil->getNumberType($phoneNumberObject);
    $carrier = '';
    $validMobile = self::INVALID;
    //if the number is valid and the type is mobile attempt to get the carrier
    if ($valid && $type === $this->phoneNumberType) {
        $carrier = $this->carrierMapper->getNameForNumber($phoneNumberObject, 'en');
        if ($carrier === '') {
            $carrier = 'unknown';
        }
        $validMobile = self::VALID;
    }
    //add to the results array
    $results[] = array($number,$carrier, $validMobile);
}

return $results;
}
}

?>
```

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: I changed the code slightly to fix one of the errors from the error log but still not having luck getting it to work. I'm not getting the following error:

Comment: [Tue Sep 07 20:00:45.639073 2021] [php7:error] [pid 6636:tid 1824] [client ::1:51081] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in C:\\UniServerZ\\www\\bayne_07_09_2021-3\\php-cli-master\\index.php on line 91, referer: http://localhost/bayne_07_09_2021-3/

Comment: The error that it is identifying is "}" ( a closing bracket)

Comment: When I removed the bracket, I then get the following:

Comment: [Tue Sep 07 20:04:50.539810 2021] [php7:error] [pid 6636:tid 1832] [client ::1:49912] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'protected' (T_PROTECTED) in C:\\UniServerZ\\www\\bayne_07_09_2021-3\\php-cli-master\\index.php on line 100, referer: http://localhost/bayne_07_09_2021-3/

Comment: I'll keep looking into it and can hopefully work my way through the errors

Comment: Allowed memory size could be any number of things, such as a large CSV, or trying to output a large object. You're going to have to troubleshoot by breaking it down into simple parts. Run the minimum code, then slowly add more in until you find where the issue is.

Comment: Yeah, I think that may be the way I'll need to work my way through it